# jquery chained select and ddslick confilct

Tags: jquery, json, select, conflict, chained

I use ddslick ([Link to page](http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick)) for creating custom select forms.

But I want to chain the options via json and implemented jquery chainded remote script by Mike Tuupola ([Link to page](http://www.appelsiini.net/2010/jquery-chained-selects)).

ddslick creates custom forms like this:

```
<div id="model" class="dd-container" style="width: 194px; ">
    <div class="dd-select" style="width: 194px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial; ">
        <input class="dd-selected-value" type="hidden" value="tet">
        <a class="dd-selected">
            <label class="dd-selected-text">1. Marke wählen:</label>
        </a>
        <span class="dd-pointer dd-pointer-down"></span>
    </div>

    <ul class="dd-options dd-click-off-close" style="width: 194px; ">
        <li>
            <a class="dd-option dd-option-selected"> 
                <input class="dd-option-value" type="hidden" rel="undefined" value="tet" name="model"> 
                <label class="dd-option-text">1. Marke wählen:</label>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="dd-option"> 
                <input class="dd-option-value" type="hidden" rel="undefined" value="bmw" name="model"> 
                <label class="dd-option-text">BMW</label>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="dd-option"> 
                <input class="dd-option-value" type="hidden" rel="undefined" value="audi" name="model"> 
                <label class="dd-option-text">Audi</label>
            </a>
       </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

The original code looks like this:

```
<select id="model" name="model"> 
    <option value="tet">1. Marke w&auml;hlen:</option> 
    <option value="bmw">BMW</option> 
    <option value="audi">Audi</option> 
</select>
```

The ddslick works fine!

But the jquery chained remote does not do anything. By choosing the first value, like BMW, the second select is not chaining values.

Here is the code:

```
(function($) {
"use strict";

$.fn.remoteChained = function(parent_selector, url, options) {

    return this.each(function() {

        /* Save this to self because this changes when scope changes. */
        var self   = this;
        var backup = $(self).clone();

        /* Handles maximum two parents now. */
        $(parent_selector).each(function() {
            $(this).bind("change", function() {

                /* Build data array from parents values. */
                var data = {};
                $(parent_selector).each(function() {
                    var id = $(this).attr("id");
                    var value = $(":selected", this).val();
                    data[id] = value;
                });

                $.getJSON(url, data, function(json) {
                    /* If select already had something selected, preserve it. */
                    var selected_key = $(':selected', self).val();

                    /* Clear the select. */
                    $("option", self).remove();

                    var option_list = [];
                    if ($.isArray(json)) {
                        /* JSON is already an array (which preserves the ordering of options) */
                        /* [["","--"],["series-1","1 series"],["series-3","3 series"]] */
                        option_list = json;
                    } else {
                        /* JSON is an JavaScript object. Rebuild it as an array. */
                        /* {"":"--","series-1":"1 series","series-3":"3 series"} */
                        for (var key in json) {
                            if (json.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                                option_list.push([key, json[key]]);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    /* Add new options from json. */
                    for (var i=0; i!==option_list.length; i++) {
                        var key = option_list[i][0];
                        var value = option_list[i][1];

                        /* Set the selected option from JSON. */
                        if ("selected" === key) {
                            selected_key = value;
                            continue;
                        }
                        var option = $("<option />").val(key).append(value);
                        $(self).append(option);
                    }

                    /* Loop option again to set selected. IE needed this... */
                    $(self).children().each(function() {
                        if ($(this).val() === selected_key) {
                            $(this).attr("selected", "selected");
                        }
                    });

                    /* If we have only the default value disable select. */
                    if (1 === $("option", self).size() && $(self).val() === "") {
                        $(self).attr("disabled", "disabled");
                    } else {
                        $(self).removeAttr("disabled");
                    }

                    /* Force updating the children. */
                    $(self).trigger("change");

                });

            });

            /* Force updating the children. */
            $(this).trigger("change");

        });
    });
};

/* Alias for those who like to use more English like syntax. */
$.fn.remoteChainedTo = $.fn.remoteChained;

})(jQuery);
```

I have integrated both script on document ready and i also tried to edit the chained script by changing all needed classes end elements to the ddslick-generated values.

Nothing works.